# While loop/ Double or quit

Tags: python, while-loop

I know how to use a `while` loop, but I'm not sure about the part where I need to make a command to double the previous score.

[The task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPz5g.png) is to double or quit.

And this is my current code :

```
import random
play = 'y'
Original = 1

while play.lower() == 'y':
    chance = random.randint(0,3)

    if chance == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")

    else:
        newnumber = Original*2
        print (newnumber)


    play = input("Play again?[y/n]: ")
```

Comment: Ask yourself these questions: the second time round the `while` loop, what value will `Original` and `newnumber` have, and what do you want them to be? What happens if the player is unlucky, but chooses to play again? And finally, do *you* feel lucky? Do you?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently repeating the same fixed output calculation over and over again:

```
newnumber = Original*2
```

`Original` is a constant since you only define it at the beginning and never change it.

You should instead use the result from the last run iteratively:

```
import random
play = 'y'
result = 1

while play.lower() == 'y':
    chance = random.randint(0,3)
    if chance == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")
        break
    else:
        result *= 2
        print(result)
    play = input("Play again?[y/n]: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for`-loop is better suited for your problem:

```
from itertools import count
import random

for pot in count():
    if random.randint(0, 3) == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")
        break
    print(2 ** pot)
    if input("Play again?[y/n]: ").lower() != 'y':
        break
```